# How to start development for mahout

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, mahout

After Installation of mahout from (http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com/2010/11/apache-mahout.html).How to Run mahout algo and from where i can get most popular as easy tutorial for mahout freshers....

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I enjoyed the http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com/2010/11/apache-mahout.html link.

Also http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout/ is good as well.

Comment: thanks and can you suggest me any tutorial for combining mahout with Pig,

Answer (score 7):

[Mahout in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182684) is also a good book to start for beginners to expert.

[Getting Started with the examples of Mahout in Action](http://alexott.blogspot.com/2012/07/getting-started-with-examples-from.html)

Answer (score 3):

http://mahout.apache.org/ This isn't a bad place to start. I think you'll find the existing documentation quite useful.

Comment: thanks nicolai.tesela and if you know how to integrate mahout tutorials for run its algorithms in hadoop and hive environment.....

Comment: That has got to be the worst place to read up documentation. Even the javadocs are terrible.